# nested loops having linear time complexity?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

```
public int[] maxSlidingWindow(int[] nums, int k) {
    int n = nums.length;
    if (n == 0) {
        return nums;
    }
    int[] result = new int[n - k + 1];
    LinkedList<Integer> dq = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!dq.isEmpty() && dq.peek() < i - k + 1) {
            dq.poll();
        }
        while (!dq.isEmpty() && nums[i] >= nums[dq.peekLast()]) {
            dq.pollLast();
        }
        dq.offer(i);
        if (i - k + 1 >= 0) {
            result[i - k + 1] = nums[dq.peek()];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As far as i understand the Worst case complexity for this code would be n*k because in the worst case the inner `while` loop would be executed k times. However the author has said that amortized time Complexity is O(n). How is that ? i don't completely understand ?

Comment: The `while` loop will indeed execulte `k` times. But eventually there will only be `n` items in the queue, hence you will, over all the loops, pop `n` times (at most).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Got it but what about the condition check in while loop !dq.isEmpty() && nums[i] >= nums[dq.peekLast()] that will most definitely be more than n right ? so why are we only considering the operation dq.pollLast in calculating the time complexity and not the condition check in while loop ? surely that is also costing time right ?

Comment: there will be at most `n-1` checks where the queue is empty, so "useless" checks. Thus at most `3n-2` times we aim to pop the queue, so `3n-2`, but that is still linear. Note that each time the condition holds, we pop the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the inner (while) loop would have a different number of iterations for each iteration of the outer (for) loop, you can't simply bound the number of iterations of that loop by k, since that bound wouldn't be tight enough.

Instead, we can try to compute the total number of operations across all iterations of the inner loop.

The outer loop adds each index exactly once to the queue (in `dq.offer(i)`).

Each index that was added to the queue, can be removed only once - either by `dq.poll()` or by `dq.pollLast()`.

Since each iteration of the `while` loop must remove an element from the queue, all the iterations of the while loop (across all iterations of the outer for loop) are bounded by `n` (since there cannot be more than `n` removals). Therefore, all the iterations of the while loop contribute `O(n)` to the total running time.

Beside the while loop, the other operations inside the outer for loop clearly take constant time, so they cost `O(n)` time when adding all the iterations of the outer loop.

Hence the total running time is `O(n)`.

Comment: Got it but what about the condition check in while loop `!dq.isEmpty() && nums[i] >= nums[dq.peekLast()]` that will most definitely be more than n right ? so why are we only considering the operation `dq.pollLast` in calculating the time complexity and not the condition check in while loop ? surely that is also costing time right ?

Comment: @dev_ios999 the evaluation of `!dq.isEmpty() && nums[i] >= nums[dq.peekLast()]` takes constant time (since `LinkedList` is a doubly linked list, so `peekLast` uses the reference to the last element). The condition can be `true` at most `n` times (since we remove an element from the queue when it's true). It can be `false` at most `n` times, one for each value of `i`, since we break out of the loop when it's `false`. Hence that condition will contribute at most O(2*n)==O(n) to the total running time.